# Can someone explain Webpack's CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack-plugin, commonschunkplugin

I get the general gist that the `CommonsChunkPlugin` looks at all the entry points, checks to see if there are common packages/dependencies between them and separates them into their own bundle.

So, let's assume I have the following configuration:

```
...
enrty : {
    entry1 : 'entry1.js', //which has 'jquery' as a dependency
    entry2 : 'entry2.js', //which has 'jquery as a dependency
    vendors : [
        'jquery',
        'some_jquery_plugin' //which has 'jquery' as a dependency
    ]
},
output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
}
...
```

### If I bundle without using `CommonsChunkPlugin`

I will end up with 3 new bundle files:

- `entry1.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry1.js` and `jquery` and contains its own runtime
- `entry2.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry2.js` and `jquery` and contains its own runtime
- `vendors.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `jquery` and `some_jquery_plugin` and contains its own runtime

This is obviously bad because I will potentially load `jquery` 3 times in the page, so we don't want that.

### If I bundle using `CommonsChunkPlugin`

Depending on what arguments I pass to `CommonsChunkPlugin` any of the following will happen:

- **CASE 1 :** If I pass `{ name : 'commons' }` I will end up with the following bundle files:

  - `entry1.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry1.js`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `entry2.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry2.js`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `vendors.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `some_jquery_plugin`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `commons.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `jquery` and contains the runtime

  This way we end up with some smaller bundles overall and the runtime is contained in the `commons` bundle. Pretty ok but not ideal.
- **CASE 2 :** If I pass `{ name : 'vendors' }` I will end up with the following bundle files:

  - `entry1.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry1.js`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `entry2.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry2.js`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `vendors.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `jquery` and `some_jquery_plugin` and contains the runtime.

  This way, again, we end up with some smaller bundles overall but the runtime is now contained in the `vendors` bundle. It's a little worse than the previous case, since the runtime is now in the `vendors` bundle.
- **CASE 3 :** If I pass `{ names : ['vendors', 'manifest'] }` I will end up with the following bundle files:

  - `entry1.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry1.js`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `entry2.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `entry2.js`, a requirement for `jquery` and does not contain the runtime
  - `vendors.bundle.js` which contains the complete code from `jquery` and `some_jquery_plugin` and does not contain the runtime
  - `manifest.bundle.js` which contains requirements for every other bundle and contains the runtime

  This way we end up with some smaller bundles overall and the runtime is contained in the `manifest` bundle. This is the ideal case.

## What I do not understand/I am not sure I understand

- In **CASE 2** why did we end up with the `vendors` bundle containing both the common code (`jquery`) and whatever remained from the `vendors` entry (`some_jquery_plugin`)? From my understanding, what the `CommonsChunkPlugin` did here was that it gathered the common code (`jquery`), and since we forced it to output it to the `vendors` bundle, it kind of "merged" the common code into the `vendors` bundle (which now only contained the code from `some_jquery_plugin`). **Please confirm or explain.**
- In **CASE 3** I do not understand what happened when we passed `{ names : ['vendors', 'manifest'] }` to the plugin. Why/how was the `vendors` bundle kept intact, containing both `jquery` and `some_jquery_plugin`, when `jquery` is clearly a common dependency, and why was the generated `manifest.bundle.js` file created the way it was created (requiring all other bundles and containing the runtime) ?

Comment: For case 1 I think you should specify the minChunks property.

Comment: I've learned so much from your _question_, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this and clearing up my confusions all this time on this plugin ❤

Comment: Maybe someone know, how these example will be looking like in Webpack 4?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This is how the `CommonsChunkPlugin` works.

A common chunk "receives" the modules shared by several entry chunks.
A good example of a complex configuration can be found in the [Webpack repository](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-commons-chunks).

The `CommonsChunkPlugin` is run during the optimization phase of Webpack, which means that it operates in memory, just before the chunks are sealed and written to the disk.

When several common chunks are defined, they are processed in order. In your case 3, it is like running the plugin twice. But please note that the `CommonsChunkPlugin` can have a more complex configuration (minSize, minChunks, etc) that impacts the way modules are moved.

**CASE 1:**

1. There are 3 `entry` chunks (`entry1`, `entry2` and `vendors`).
2. The configuration sets the `commons` chunk as a common chunk.
3. The plugin processes the `commons` common chunk (since the chunk does not exist, it is created):

   1. It collects the modules that are used more than once in the other chunks: `entry1`, `entry2` and `vendors` use `jquery` so the module is removed from these chunks and is added to the `commons` chunk.
   2. The `commons` chunk is flagged as an `entry` chunk while the `entry1`, `entry2` and `vendors` chunks are unflagged as `entry`.
4. Finally, since the `commons` chunk is an `entry` chunk it contains the runtime and the `jquery` module.

**CASE 2:**

1. There are 3 `entry` chunks (`entry1`, `entry2` and `vendors`).
2. The configuration sets the `vendors` chunk as a common chunk.
3. The plugin processes the `vendors` common chunk:

   1. It collects the modules that are used more than once in the other chunks: `entry1` and `entry2` use `jquery` so the module is removed from these chunks (note that it is not added to the `vendors` chunk because the `vendors` chunk already contains it).
   2. The `vendors` chunk is flagged as an `entry` chunk while the `entry1` and `entry2` chunks are unflagged as `entry`.
4. Finally, since the `vendors` chunk is an `entry` chunk, it contains the runtime and the `jquery`/`jquery_plugin` modules.

**CASE 3:**

1. There are 3 `entry` chunks (`entry1`, `entry2` and `vendors`).
2. The configuration sets the `vendors` chunk and the `manifest` chunk as common chunks.
3. The plugin creates the `manifest` chunk as it does not exist.
4. The plugin processes the `vendors` common chunk:

   1. It collects the modules that are used more than once in the other chunks: `entry1` and `entry2` use `jquery` so the module is removed from these chunks (note that it is not added to the `vendors` chunk because the `vendors` chunk already contains it).
   2. The `vendors` chunk is flagged as an `entry` chunk while the `entry1` and `entry2` chunks are unflagged as `entry`.
5. The plugin processes the `manifest` common chunk (since the chunk does not exist, it is created):

   1. It collects the modules that are used more than once in the other chunks: as there are no modules used more than once, no module is moved.
   2. The `manifest` chunk is flagged as `entry` chunk while the `entry1`, `entry2` and `vendors` are unflagged as `entry`.
6. Finally, since the `manifest` chunk is an `entry` chunk it contains the runtime.

Comment: A few things I want to ask/clarify, please add these points to your answer too: 1) Can you do the same step by step explanation for CASE 1 just so the answer is 1000% complete? 2) Running the plugin with `{ names : ['vendors', 'manifest'] }` is like running it twice, once with `{ name : 'vendors' }` and once with `{ name : 'manifest' }`, correct?  3) When we say "The plugin processes a common chunk" we mean it creates the contents it'll spit in the `bundle.js` file, in memory, correct? 4) Until it's "processed all common chunks" it hasn't written any output to a file at all, it's all in memory

Comment: 5) Considering 2) from above and your explanation "It collects the modules that are used more than 1 time in the other chuncks: as there is no modules used more than 1 time, no module is moved." this means that the second invocation of the plugin works with the in memory results of the first invocation of the plugin (the `jquery` module has already been removed from the other chunks, so it just finds one instance where the complete `jquery` code exists, that is the contents of the `vendors` chunk), right? 6) "chunks" == in memory, "bundles" == output, right?

Comment: 7) the plugin assigning the final "common" chunk as an `entry` chunk instead of a `normal` one, is, I suppose, default behaviour, right? Thanks so much for your answer

Comment: (actually ignore 7) :) )

Comment: I have one more question, if you feel like answering. Let's say that in my example from above, `entry1.js` and `entry2.js` had another common file between them, other than the `jquery` file, let's call it `ownLib.js`. In CASE 2 and CASE 3, `ownLib.js` would end up in the `vendors.bundle.js` correct? How would you make it so that common files other than vendor files are separated into their own chunk, apart from the `vendors` chunk? Sorry for bothering you, but I am still learning how to use webpack

Comment: Yes that is right: `ownLib.js` would be placed in the first common chunck. If you want to collect common dependencies in another chunck, you have to pass something like this: `{ names : ['common', 'vendors', 'manifest'] }`.

Comment: Great question, great answer, great discussion. Seems like I get it finally.

Comment: @LaurentEtiemble: 
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['common', 'vendor', 'manifest'],
      chunks: ['main', 'Home'],
    }), this is my config but webpack runtime is present in all common chunks.Can you explain why?

Comment: @BhargaviGunda I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that you only tell it to run the plugin on chunks `main` and `Home` instead of everything?

Comment: I have spent the last **day** reading CommonsChunkPlugin docs and this is the first place I have read that, after executing, the processed chunks "are unflagged as entry".  That basically explains everything I was having trouble with -- if I could upvote more than once, I would.

Comment: What would be really useful for this answer is the final configuration that achieves what the OP was after. There's so many variations mentioned in the question and answer that it's very hard to put together what the actual result looks like!

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. By any chance maybe somebody knows how to transfer those 3 variants to Webpack 4?

Comment: Can you explain this? 'Finally, since the commons chunk is an entry chunk it contains the runtime and the jquery module.'